# Django Cache - Issue displaying images retrieved from cache

Tags: django, python-memcached

I am using django 1.4, python 2.7, Memcache,  python-memcached, and easy-thumbnails.

When I try to access an item page using cached data I get the following template error:

```
Couldn't get the thumbnail uploads/items/item_images/logo.jpeg: 'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'instance'
```

When I access the data in question from the data base in the shell I get:

```
>>> log = item.get_logo()
>>> logo
<ImageFieldFile: uploads/items/item_images/logo.png>
>>> logo.instance
<Media: uploads/items/item_images/logo.png>
```

When I try to access the same data from cache I get:

```
>>> cache.set('logo',item.get_logo())
>>> logo = cache.get('logo')
>>> logo
<ImageFieldFile: uploads/items/item_images/logo.png>
>>> logo.instance
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'instance'
```

My question is how do you cache an `ImageFieldFile` so that it is retrievable in its original state? I need to pass that object to my template for use with easy-thumbnails.

Comment: Django serializes querysets and objects when you cache them because memcached is a key value store. My guess is it stops short of serializing images, maybe because it is a byte string? Can you cache the byte string yourself using the id or something as a key?

Comment: @Enrico I looked into your suggestion and could not get it to work. My answer below is my current solution but am open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So instead of trying to cache an `ImageFieldFile` I cached the object (`Media`) that `ImageFieldFile` resides in and now everything works.

**Database:**

```
>>> logo = item.get_logo()
>>> logo
<Media: uploads/items/item_images/logo.png>
>>> logo.image #this is what I was trying to cache before
<ImageFieldFile: uploads/items/item_images/logo.png>
>>> logo.image.instance
<Media: uploads/items/item_images/logo.png>
```

**Cache:**

```
>>> cache.set('logo',logo)
>>> cachedLogo = cache.get('logo')
>>> logo
<Media: uploads/items/item_images/logo.png>
>>> logo.image
<ImageFieldFile: uploads/items/item_images/logo.png>
>>> logo.image.instance
<Media: uploads/items/item_images/logo.png>
```